# ESLint autofix ignore rule

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using ESLint in vscode with option `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true`.

Basically, I want:

1. Ignore 1 particular rule **for fixing**: [prefer-const](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const)
2. See all the warnings and errors highlighted in editor (including `prefer-const`)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking to do the same with the no-debugger rule.  Hard to put breakpoints in my code if it auto removes debugger statements.

Comment: Nope. I guess I'm gonna wait for [#7649](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7549). You can try [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/208#issuecomment-323753480) if you are using vscode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than introducing another likely to soon be unmaintained plugin into your code, with its own dependencies, here's a better solution.

In the latest version of the eslint plugin for vscode, there's a new settings. You can read about here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Specifically `eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode` and `eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules`

By adding these settings in the vscode config it's possible to disable autofix on save specifically for this annoying prefer-const rule.

Make sure to read the note in the docs that says:

> Please note that if eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode is set to problems, the eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules is ignored.

```
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
        "source.fixAll": true
    },
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": [
        "!prefer-const",
        "*"
    ],
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "all"
```

This takes care of it being autofixed by vscode.

To take care of it being fixed by your cli build process refer to this answer: [How to disable autofix for specific rules in eslint using CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885099/how-to-disable-autofix-for-specific-rules-in-eslint-using-cli)

Sadly there's no fix yet at the eslint server level, so this solution is specific to vscode.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be a new plugin: [eslint-plugin-no-autofix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-autofix)

```json
{
  "plugins": ["no-autofix"],
  "rules": {
    "prefer-const": "off",
    "no-autofix/prefer-const": "warn",
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like there is no way to do the same for non-core plugin rules