# ESLint: How to specify rules that can be auto-fixed (using --fix) in the config file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Can I control which rules `eslint --fix` auto fixes?

I have multiple rules but I don't want all the fixable rules to be fixed on doing `eslint --fix`. Is there a way to specify them in the config file?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same task to do: auto fix eslint issues by the rule. Looks like there is no way to do it, so I came up with **workaround**.

- Remove "extends" from .eslintrc
- Remove all rules except rule(s) to fix from .eslintrc
- Run eslint --fix
- Revert .eslintrc

For rules that come from "extends" I added them into .eslintrc by myself at step 2.

Comment: Ouch... that sucks so deep.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a plugin for that [no-autofix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-no-autofix). This way you can blacklist some rules, e.g. rules you want to stay non-fixed.

Note that it works only with core ESLint rules, so it won't prevent auto-fix for the rules from other plugins.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55077343/3354444

Answer (score 0):

Using CLI you can ignore the config file and run only the rules you list:

```
eslint --no-eslintrc --rule 'semi: [1, "always"]'
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface for the rest of the params you may need