# How to disable autofix for specific rules in eslint using CLI?

Tags: eslint

I want to be able to disable the rules that --fix fixes when running eslint in a console for a repo. The reason for this is because --fix leads to undesirable behavior for our jsdoc eslint rules. It creates invalid or sometimes empty jsdoc in our project- which typically leads to even more eslint rules (due to our configuration) and leads to tons of manual fixing or removal.

I want to just run --fix without it touching any jsdoc rules so that I can complete jsdoc manually- while eslint fixes all the rest of the rules.

I came across this SO question- but package mentioned in the answer does not support non-core plugins.

[ESLint autofix ignore rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443478/eslint-autofix-ignore-rule)

Is there anything I can do short of modifying my eslintrc file every time I run the linter or using vscode for linting and modifying the config for the web editor instead? Its not a big deal for newer files- but linting legacy files is a chore when there's hundreds of spacing errors that I can't automatically fix easily.

Comment: Just came across this and discovered that as of a week ago the package linked above now "supports all eslint core rules and 3rd-party plugins(except for scoped packages)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, that already exists, right? If a user wants to avoid auto-fixing a particular rule, they can use:

```
eslint somedir --fix --rule "somerule: 0"
```

Or, if they want to whitelist a set of rules, they can use &nbps `--no-eslintrc` and specify rules directly or use `--config` and point to a particular config that they want to use for fixes.

Comment: I was aware of the rule arg but since there's like 20ish jsdoc rules we have setup- it would be a pain to have to remember how to copy and paste the super long command just to fix it. I guess its an option though. Ideally we also don't want to have 2 configs- was more looking of how to modify our current config file to support this. But if there's no easier alternative we may have to choose one of the options you mentioned

Comment: mm OK, its your choice

Comment: Howabout `cat disable-rules.txt | xargs eslint src —fix —rule`

Comment: hey. can you find any other method

Comment: hey.. is my answer useful

Answer (score 13):

Using an `.eslintrc.js` file you can do something like this:

```
const isFixMode = process.argv.includes('--fix');

const config = {
  rules: {
    'no-console': 'error',
    ...(isFixMode && {
      'no-console': 'warn',
    }),
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: I'd guess this doesn't work unless you're calling eslint from the cli; for api users you can just filter the results array and remove the rule in question when calling ESLint.outputFixes

Comment: You might also want to include `--fix-dry-run` (introduced in eslint 4.9.0), and `--fix-to-stdout` for `eslint_d`. Both are used/supported by [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/9fe7b1fe6a23fb55e6d782293585d58193123f59/autoload/ale/fixers/eslint.vim#L53-L82) and possibly other editor integrations. e.g. `process.argv.some(arg => arg.startsWith("--fix"))` or `const fixArgs = ["--fix", "--fix-to-stdout", "--fix-dry-run"]; const isFixMode = process.argv.some(arg => fixArgs.includes(arg));`

Answer (score 2):

I found this: https://github.com/chiefmikey/eslint-plugin-disable-autofix.

Tested with `@typescript-eslint` and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here’s another idea. Convert you `.eslinrc` file into `.eslintrc.js`. This will allow you to programmatically set eslint config.

Then you could use the [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) library to detect the `—fix` flag and set a Boolean to determine which eslint rules you would like to disable.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with maybe a short code snippet of an example of using commander in relation to the fix flag? I was planning on reading the docs later- but think it will be useful for future readers if the code example is in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me was setting the rule to `warn` and afterwards run.
`eslint . --fix --quiet`

It is not an error anymore, but better than getting my code broken by a erroneous fixer.